# triggering post request, a get request is triggered rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I will be very thankful if anyone can help me out in this.

I have a route that is a post request and I am using it as a post request in my views but when I hit the route it shows get request in the browser.

This is what I have in routes:

```
  resources :candidate_folders, only: [:create, :show, :update, :destroy] do
    member do    
      post '/move_job_slot/:folder/:job_slot', to: 'candidate_folders#move_job_slot', as: :move_job_slot
    end
  end
```

This is how I am using it in my views

```
  <%= link_to link, method: :post, class:'is-text' do %>
    <div class="rounded border hover:bg-gray-100 py-2 px-4"> 
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center space-x-1">
        <p class="truncate">
          <%= icon 'fa', 'folder' %>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <%= folder.name %>
        </p>
        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 whitespace-nowrap">
          <%= folder.n_job_slots %>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

[image]

Comment: Change `method: :get` to `method: :post`

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly wrote ```:get``` it was ```:post``` and I still got the same error correcting it now

Comment: @BurhanGardezi what do you mean by "when I hit the route"? Yes, browser will do a get request (it's what browsers do), but clicking the link should do a post request. If you want to visit the url with the browser you'll have to define the get request. I'm not sure why your link is a post request... you're not submitting any user-entered data.

Answer (score 2):

Link_to by default triggers a get request. In order to make a post for rails 6 or less you can use `method: :post` however for rails 7 and above `method: "post"` as well as `remote: true` option with `link_to` is deprecated since rails 7. So now with `link_to` you would do something similar `data: { turbo_method: "post" }`  to achieve the same behaviour of a non-get request.

> https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to
> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#replacements-for-rails-ujs-functionality